# Change HTML values in JAVA (Android)

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio

I have string value in `HTML` get web. Stored in varible `s` as shown below.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ubR8WfwQTkw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

**Problem**

I want to change the width value `560` to `250`.

I try to use  `s.replace("560", "250");` but its not working.

Any clues ...how can i change it.

Comment: have you escaped the double quotes ? like this "\""

Comment: What actually happens ? what's the value of s after executing the previous line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works:

```
String s = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ubR8WfwQTkw\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
String replace = s.replace("560", "250");
System.out.println(replace);
```

If you print `s` you'll see `560` because Strings are immutable in java. If you don't want to declare a new String you could do in this way:

```
String s = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ubR8WfwQTkw\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
s = s.replace("560", "250");
System.out.println(s);
```